# x-axis not updating for dc.js filter

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvinci/J9ghN/

I've created a pie chart broken down by year and I've set the min and max range for the line chart based off the dimension. However, when I select a year, the range does not update. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var yearRingChart = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year");
var tpslineChart = dc.lineChart("#chart-tps");

var data2 = [
{date: "10/01/2012", hits: 1, tps: 100, http_status:200},
{date: "10/01/2012", hits: 1, tps: 90, http_status:302},
{date: "01/02/2013", hits: 1, tps: 100, http_status:200},
{date: "01/02/2013", hits: 1, tps: 10, http_status:302},
{date: "01/03/2013", hits: 0, tps: 300, http_status:200},
{date: "01/03/2013", hits: 1, tps: 10, http_status:302},
{date: "01/04/2013", hits: 1, tps: 90, http_status:200},
{date: "01/04/2013", hits: 1, tps: 0, http_status:302},
];

var ndx2 = crossfilter(data2);
// normalize/parse data
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

data2.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.Year=d.date.getFullYear();
});

var yearDim = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;});
var tpsDim = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});

var tps_total = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.tps;});
var tps_graph = tpsDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.tps;});

var minDate = tpsDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
var maxDate = tpsDim.top(1)[0].date;

yearRingChart
.width(200).height(200)
.dimension(yearDim)
.group(tps_total)
.innerRadius(50);

tpslineChart
.width(500).height(200)
.dimension(tpsDim)
.group(tps_graph)
.brushOn(false)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
.xUnits(d3.time.day)
.yAxisLabel("TPS")
.elasticY(true)
.margins({ top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 50 })
//.renderlet(function (chart) {chart.selectAll("g.x text").attr('dx', '-30').attr('transform',     "rotate(-90)");})
;

dc.renderAll();
```

Comment: The easiest way to grow and shrink the x-axis would be with a brush.

Comment: The issue with the brush is that you can't just click a particular year, you'd have to mess around to highlight it fully. Unless you did a bar chart with a single bar being a year. Still it wouldn't be as straightforward.

Comment: You can programtically set the brush: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6498580

Comment: In order for the x-axis to update on the chart redraw, I needed to set the elasticX to true. By default, it is static.

    .elasticX(true)

However, even with that set, it still won't pull in the new dates. So I used an onclick event to change the x-axis on the fly. If anyone has a more natural way to do this in dc.js, let me know.
This fiddle shows the fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/tvinci/mXsHf/